# XQuery: the "for" loop repeats more than expected

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, exist-db

I have to recognize I can't get the logic of XQuery queries...
So there is my problem.

**I have this XML file:**

```
<doc id="book_1">
    <title>Title</title>
    <div type="chapter" id="ch_1">
        <head>Chapter 1</head>
        <p><pb n="1"/> text text text text</p>
        <p>text text text text</p>
        <p>text text KEYWORD text text</p>
        <p><pb n="2"/> text text text text</p>
        <p>text KEYWORD text text text</p>
        <p>text text text text</p>
        <p><pb n="3"/> text text text text</p>
        <p>text text text text</p>
    </div>
    <div type="chapter" id="ch_2">
        <head>Chapter 2</head>
        <p><pb n="4"/> text text text text</p>
        <p>text text text KEYWORD text</p>
        <p>text KEYWORD text text text</p>
        <p><pb n="5"/> text text text text</p>
        <p>text text text text</p>
        <p>text text text text</p>
        <p><pb n="6"/> text text text text</p>
        <p>text KEYWORD text text text</p>
    </div>
    etc. etc. etc.
</doc>
```

I'm looking for "KEYWORD" through this file and I want to be able to know on which page (`pb`) each keyword was found.

**My current XQuery:**

```
xquery version "3.1";
import module namespace kwic="http://exist-db.org/xquery/kwic";
 
let $query := <query><bool><term>KEYWORD</term></bool></query>

for $hit in collection("my_collection/my_files")//doc[ft:query(., $query)] 
let $hit_expanded := kwic:expand($hit)
let $book_id := data($hit_expanded//exist:match/ancestor::doc/@id)
let $page := data($hit_expanded//exist:match/preceding::pb[1]/@n)

return
    kwic:summarize($hit, <config width="40" link="book_id={$book_id}__page={$page}"/>)
```

In my logic:

i) "*for*" loop will call "*return*" each time "*query*" is found;

ii) for each found query I will look for the book id (*$book_id*) and for **the only one, immediately preceding, number of page** (*$page*).

**This is what I get:** (pay attention to the page number in @href)

```
1
<p>
    <span class="previous">...text text text </span>
    <a class="hi" href="book_id=book_1__page=1 2 4 6">KEYWORD</a>
    <span class="following">text text text...</span>
</p>

2
<p>
    <span class="previous">...text text text</span>
    <a class="hi" href="book_id=book_1__page=1 2 4 6">KEYWORD</a>
    <span class="following"> text text text...</span>
</p>

3
<p>
    <span class="previous">... text text text </span>
    <a class="hi" href="book_id=book_1__page=1 2 4 6">KEYWORD</a>
    <span class="following"> text text text...</span>
</p>
    etc. etc. etc.
```

Ok, I understand that it repeats the number of distinct pages "*n*" times (where *n* = number of KEYWORDS found in distinct pages).
But why it does it? I mean, i) we have to be in the “*for*” loop with **only one** “*query*” result by time and ii) I explicitly said to take the **only first one** *[1]* , immediately preceding, number of the page for "*query*" ...

**This is a result I desire:** (pay attention to the page number in @href)

```
1
<p>
    <span class="previous">...text text text </span>
    <a class="hi" href="book_id=book_1__page=1">KEYWORD</a>
    <span class="following">text text text...</span>
</p>

2
<p>
    <span class="previous">...text text text</span>
    <a class="hi" href="book_id=book_1__page=2">KEYWORD</a>
    <span class="following"> text text text...</span>
</p>

3
<p>
    <span class="previous">... text text text </span>
    <a class="hi" href="book_id=book_1__page=4">KEYWORD</a>
    <span class="following"> text text text...</span>
</p>
    etc. etc. etc.
```

So, that I miss in logic of XQuery queries?

**EDIT**: It changes nothing if I put the page numbers query directly to the *return*, like this:

```
kwic:summarize($hit, <config width="40" link="book_id={$book_id}__page={data($hit_expanded//exist:match/preceding::pb[1]/@n)}"/>)
```

**EDIT 2**: There is my collection.xconf file:

```
<collection xmlns="http://exist-db.org/collection-config/1.0">
    <index xmlns:kwic="http://exist-db.org/xquery/kwic"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <lucene>
            <text qname="doc"/>
            <text qname="div"/>
            <text qname="p"/>
          </lucene>
    </index>
</collection>
```

Comment: Do you really want to search the whole `doc`? Wouldn't `for $hit in collection("my_collection/my_files")//p[ft:query(., $query)]` give the right selection?

Comment: You are absolutely right. It seems to be more logic and should certainly improve the query performance if I query directly a paragraph (`p`). But there are two problems:

Comment: 1) I tried to query `doc`, `div` and `p` and I don't know why but each query return a different number of results. For example, I have two documents with 2 _"KEYWORDs"_ in the first one and with 3 _"KEYWORDs"_ in the second one (in another word, I have 5 occurrences in 2 documents). 
When I query `doc` it will return 5 results, when I query `div` it'll return 7 results and, finally, with `p` query I have 4 results... I have no idea why... (Just to note, in my `collection.xconf` of eXist I have an index on each of these elements.) So, I have to query `doc` to get a right number of results.

Comment: 2) Secondly. In my query I use `kwic:expand` which return me found keywords (tagged with `exist:match`) in context. (I tried not to use `kwic:expand` but I can't get the similar result.) This context is depending on query tag (for example, if I query `doc` I get whole document as context, if I query `div`, my context will be this `div`, and so on...) 
So, thanks to this function, I can query ancestors, preceding and other neighbourhood tags...

Comment: So if I have a `doc` context I can get `ancestor::doc/@id` and `preceding::pb[1]/@n`. With `p` context I can’t get `doc_id` and I get preceding page number only if this preceding page is in the same paragraph as found keywords.

Comment: Please add your for-loop code as well as the relevant index configuration. Then it is very likely your problem can be solved.

Comment: I added `collection.xconf` to my question. My for-loop is in the question. After Martin Honnen question, I rechecked all my files and there was a problem with the structure of some files (a few files doesn't have `p` or `div`); it explains a difference of the results when query `doc` or `div` or `p`. So my first remark in comments above has to be ignored. All the rest stay the same.